# ontouchstart and ontouchend in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, touch

I am currently using the following for every element I want to change the class of on touch:

```
ontouchstart="$(this).addClass('select');" ontouchend="$(this).removeClass('select');"
```

I was wondering if there is something like this?:

```
$("#element").touchstart(function(){
    $(this).addClass('select');
},
function(){
   $(this).removeClass('select');
});
```

That I would be able to list all the elements that I want to have this property. I have tried so many things and cant get it to work.

Comment: why did you not use onmousedown onmouseup event? You don't need JQ at all

Comment: @Reign.85 As far as I am aware, the onmousedown does not trigger when a user touches the screen, only slightly after.

Comment: nevermind, in fact, touchstart get better performance on mobile device.  Forget my comment. But you still can do it without JQ, check my new answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I ended up just using this:

```
$('#nav li').bind('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('select');
}).bind('touchend', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('select');
});
```

Answer (score 15):

Without JQUERY :

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
 e.currentTarget.className = "select";
});
```

With JQUERY

```
$('#nav ul li a').on('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).addClass('select');
});
```

Actually, on() get better performance than bind(), check [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: And `bind()` has been deprecated a while, so if you land here, `on()` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It has some normalized events, which are quite possibly what you need. Here's a list of special events from jQuery Mobile's API reference: [little link](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

You care about those:

> vmousedown
>
> ```
> Normalized event for handling touchstart or mousedown events
> ```
>
> vmousemove
>
> ```
> Normalized event for handling touchmove or mousemove events
> ```
>
> vmouseup
>
> ```
> Normalized event for handling touchend or mouseup events
> ```

Comment: So there is no way to do it simply with just jquery?

Comment: @Ian34 I expect you can just rewrite the events the way jQuery Mobile did, but there's no reason to "reinvent the wheel" :)

Comment: Yeah, it just seems like a waste to import the entire plugin just to enable the touchstart stuff

Comment: @Ian34 You can customize your download to include only the core stuff (including events). Then the file would be barely 17KB. Not **too much** if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `:hover` pseudo-class for this? It seems to me that this is a temporary change of the CSS rules of the `nav_li` element.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and belongs in the question's 'comments' section.

Comment: The `:hover` pseudo-class messes up when dragging on the screen (scrolling). For some reason, on android phones, it highlights a random area on the screen when scrolling.

Comment: @lan34 `:hover` wasn't designed for use with touch screen devices. When input (a touch) is detected, it triggers `:active` classes.