# Javascript Touch click button without lifting finger

Tags: javascript, button, touch

Is it possible in touchdevices to click a button without lifting the finger?
Almost like swiping a piano. I am using this for a wireless gamepad for touchdevices.

Is it possible in javascript or in Jquery?

I have this code now.

https://jsfiddle.net/11fz6nen/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .button {
              width: 100px;
              height: 100px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Click button Touch</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            //<![CDATA[
            window.onload = function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#button1').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "red");
                    });
                    $('#button2').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "green");
                    });
                    $('#button3').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "blue");
                    });
                    $('#button4').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "orange");
                    });
                    $('#button5').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "pink");
                    });
                    $('#button6').click(function() {
                        $('body').css("background-color", "purple");
                    });
                });
            }
            //]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="button" id="button1">test1</button>
        <button class="button" id="button2">test2</button>
        <button class="button" id="button3">test3</button>
        <button class="button" id="button4">test4</button>
        <button class="button" id="button5">test5</button>
        <button class="button" id="button6">test6</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried the `onTouchstart` attribute? Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339923/ontouchstart-and-ontouchend-in-jquery

Comment: I have tried onTouchstart and i cant get it to work.